# NSInvalidArgumentException between Swift & Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift4

I am working on a project that's using both Objective-C and swift.  We're using the bridge to connect them together.

I have a swift class that needs to call a delegate function, but I keep getting NSInvalidArgumentExceptions when I try to call the Objective-C function.

View (Swift):

```
// the-view.swift
//...
@objc public protocol YMUReceiptsContainerViewDelegate: Any {
    func receiptsContainerView(view: YMUReceiptsContainerView, didOpenAuthViewWithURL: NSString)
}
//...

func triggerUpdate() {
    // Calling this "triggerUpdate" function throws NSInvalidArgumentException
   // NOTE: self.delegate is the controller-view

    self.delegate?.receiptsContainerView(view:self, didOpenAuthViewWithURL:NSString(string: "https://yahoo.com"))
}
```

Delegate (Objective-C):

```
// the-view-controller.m
//...
- (void)receiptsContainerView: (YMUReceiptsContainerView *)view didOpenAuthViewWithURL:(NSString *)url {
    //do stuff...
}
//...
```

When I call the "triggerUpdate()" function from Swift, I get the NSInvalidArgumentException.  Is it clear to anyone what I'm doing wrong?  I can't seem to get the arguments to play nicely between Swift & Objective-C.

Comment: `NSInvalidArgumentException` usually happens when there's a nil pointer where a non-nil object is required.

Comment: Yup.. that's what was happening, but my question was about syntax.  I got the answer anyways.  Just needed to fix the way that I defined the method in the protocol so it mapped the properties correctly to Objective-C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer... The way that I defined the arguments in my protocol was wrong.  I needed to change the first parameter in the protocol to not require a label.  Adding "_" before the first parameter fixed the problem.

```
// the-view.swift
//...
@objc public protocol YMUReceiptsContainerViewDelegate: Any {
    // Adding the "_" before "view" makes the parameter not require a label.
    func receiptsContainerView(_ view: YMUReceiptsContainerView, 
         didOpenAuthViewWithURL: NSString)
    }
//...

func triggerUpdate() {
    // Removed the "view" label when calling the function too...

    self.delegate?.receiptsContainerView(self, 
        didOpenAuthViewWithURL:NSString(string: "https://yahoo.com"))
}
```

With just that one small change, everything works.  The crux of the problem was that when I defined the function in Objective-C, the first parameter doesn't have a label.  Then, in my delegate, I was defining the param with a label.  So, the arguments weren't being passed correctly from Swift to Obj-C.  Adding the "_" before the first param in the protocol made params map correctly.

Comment: If you don't have a documentation reference for this (I just did a quick scan of the 4.0.3 versions of the Apple books and didn't spot it, but could easily have missed it) could you maybe raise a documentation bug against it? (bugreport.apple.com)

Comment: Well, It's kind of in there, but wasn't called out explicitly.  It was just a little unclear to me how to write the protocol correctly in this particular case.  They do mention it here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html.  However, it isn't explained all that well.

Comment: "However, it isn't really explained all that well" - sadly a capsule review of the Swift book ;-( I found it used in code samples, e.g. in the *Delegate* section of [Adopting Cocoa Design Patterns](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-ID6), but not stated as required anywhere – and the error you got was, let's say, "unhelpful".

Comment: Agreed... When I get a few minutes, I'll post a little comment on bugreport.apple.com (which I'm sure they'll politely ignore).  They sure haven't done a very good job of documenting the quirks between objective-c & swift.  Maybe they were hoping that the pain of development using the bridge without proper documentation would force teams to move to swift more aggressively.